# Mercurial Pull Error

Tags: mercurial, perforce, pull

I am new to the dvcs world.  My company uses perforce and I'm not a fan so I thought I'd try to use mercurial as a front end.  I set it up on a windows machine with TortiseHG, enabled the Perfarce extension, did a small checkout (limiting the target revision) and pulled for the rest.  This seemed to be more robust than clone alone.

This seems to be working fairly well as I've been able to get up to change 8700 or so.

My problem is with an error in the perforce repo.  During the `hg pull` command it hits an error `abort: file path/to/file.pl missing in p4 workspace` and rolls back the transaction.

Is there anyway to bypass or skip that file and force it to continue since this is not a file I care about.

Update:
According to the admin, the file in question was a symlink.  Would that cause this kind of problem?  If so, how do I/admin fix or bypass it?

Is it possible to check out just a part of a perforce repo rather than the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with symlinks that are not supported out on Windows.

This is fixed in the current version of Perfarce, which should appear in TortoiseHG soon.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  According to this [http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/upcoming-release-notes] it seems that the next version won't be out till July.  Do you know if it's possible to upgrade Perfarce independently?  Do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: In the tortoisehg install folder there is an extension-versions.txt file.  It says the version of perfarce installed is d3f3cadd27cd [http://www.kingswood-consulting.co.uk/hg/perfarce/rev/d3f3cadd27cd].
Based on this, there doesn't seem to be any changes relating to symlinks (http://www.kingswood-consulting.co.uk/hg/perfarce/).  Which revision should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have someone check that the Perforce repository is actually in a sane state. There might be something broken which you triggered and the data of your company might be at stake, so someone should definitely look what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had an admin look at it and they said it was a symlink.  Would a symlink cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Mercurial supports symlinks as of 0.9.4 (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SymbolicLinks). If you're using the latest version of Mercurial and Perfarce, file a bug report.